# mysql.connect_timeout in php vs connect_timeout in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, timeout, database-connection

What is the difference between :

```
mysql.connect_timeout
```

that we can find in `php.ini`

and

```
connect_timeout
```

that belongs to MySQL configuration (`show variables`).

Knowing that Apache server and MySQL server are two distant VPS with a VIP between them, what is the value considered by the whole environment (Varnish + Apache + MySQL)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`mysql.connect_timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout) tells PHP how long it should wait for a response from the MySQL server when it tries to connect.

[`connect_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) in MySQL configuration tells the MySQL server how long to wait for a connect packet from the client before responding with a `Bad handshake` error.

Apache is not involved in either of these timeouts, they're just between PHP and MySQL. First PHP connects to MySQL; if it doesn't get a response before `mysql.connect_timeout`, it will report an error. Once that succeeds, PHP sends a `connect` packet to MySQL; if it doesn't do that within `connect_timeout`, MySQL will report an error and close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest timeout within the stack would be essentially act as your timeout. If you hit a timeout, the longer timeout will never get hit, so it won't matter.

Comment: Paul is this really true given that mysql.connect_timeout handles PHP to MySQL and connect_timeout handles MySQL to PHP?